# how can i compare value from the list of webElement and click on the required value from the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
        {System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/flights");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")).clear();
            List<WebElement> Cities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autoCompleteItem']"));

    for (WebElement size1 : Cities )
    {
        String str = size1.getText(); 
            System.out.println(str);
                if(size1.getText().equals("LON"))
                {
                    size1.click();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("match not found"); 
                }   
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :

```
     driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/flights");

     driver.findElement(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")).clear();
     try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     driver.findElement(By.id("hp-widget__sfrom")).sendKeys("LON");


     List<WebElement> Cities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='autoCompleteItem']//span[contains(.,'London, UK - All Airports')]"));
   for (WebElement size1 : Cities )
   {
           String str = size1.getText(); 

         if(size1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("London, UK - All Airports"))
         {
              System.out.println(size1.getText());
             size1.click();
             break;
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("match not found"); 
         }   
     }
   }
}
```

If your value in below in dropdown then need to focus that element first.

Comment: So i do not require to get them into the list?

Comment: Make sure your xpath should return the value you required

Comment: what is Options ? under for loop?

Answer (score 0):

if you only wants to check for text then you could simple form an xpath and avoid this loop.

```
try{
    WebElement city =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='autoCompleteItem' and text()='LON']");
    city.click();
}catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
    System.out.print("Element not Found");
}
```

Comment: Sorry bro the xpath you have mentioned is not working

Comment: how about this `//div[@class='autoCompleteItem' and contains(text(),'LON)']` try the firebut to validate the xpath. rather than checking in webdriver script if you are.

Comment: yes i tried the same //div[@class='autoCompleteItem' and contains(text(),'GOI')] but i thins the " ' " was placed improper i tried that also but its not working , please i request you to check it on makemytrip.com

Comment: bro your xpath is correct but the thing is it very tricky its not possible to just give the xpath and select it, please if you have time have look its bit different you might find a new thing